# Graph algorithm to group nodes by level and group size

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, directed-graphs

I have a directed graph representing some topics organized as follows (below screenshot is a subset of the graph):

[image]

I'm looking for an algorithm to group a set of nodes (in blue in the diagram) following this logic:

- **Groups as evenly sized as possible**: we don't want groups with very few nodes and others with lots of nodes
- **If multiple groups have the same nodes, take the most specific group** ie the group that's the closer successor

**Now I know multiple solutions may exist for the same problem** (eg 4 groups of 2 or 2 groups of 4?) but if there are existing algorithms similar to what I'm looking for I would be greatly if you can share their names so I can start testing them and see what works best for me and tweak them if needed.

**Q: Do you know algorithms designed to perform similar types of node grouping?**

Comment: Hi D.W: sorry for the lack of clarity, **same items=** same nodes from the set (A,B,C... G,H.I) we're trying to group. **more speceific=** a more direct successor

Comment: As for the tradeoffs I don't know yet, I plan on running the algorithm with various parameters, and crowdsource the rating of the output to settle for what most people prefer.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  I hope you can revise the question to state the problem clearly.  Apparently there's a set of nodes, and some other set, and I'm not clear on how they are related, or what an item is, or how it relates to a node.  I don't know what a direct successor is or how to use that to evaluate a group.  If you don't know how you want to trade them off, you don't know what answer you want from the algorithm yet, so I don't see how we can suggest an algorithm.

Comment: No need to be sorry. **Item:** term removed, I only talk about "nodes". **direct successor**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Basic_terminology (here the closer the successor, the more specific). **Tradeoffs**: I have some general principles (not too many groups, groups evenly sized, the more specific the better) but don't know the exact balance yet. I will use crowd feedback to rate the output based on various tuning parameters. So right now I'm just looking for names of algorithms close to what I'm after so I can start experimenting and refining my approach.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a group.  Can you define your terms precisely?  I would understand "groups" as a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of the set of nodes, but then I don't understand how multiple groups can have  the same nodes.  I still don't see any clear description of what is meant by a "more specific group"; saying it is about direct successor doesn't help because I don't know what the direct successor of a group is (that terminology is used for nodes, not sets of nodes), nor do I understand what you mean to "take" a group or not take it.

Comment: What does "the group that's closer successor" mean? Assuming that you mean a subset of vertices by "group," and how can a set of vertices be *a closer successor*? Do you mean that the mentioned set of vertices have the same successor?